# How to broadcast audio *from* my website to clients

Tags: web-services, audio, broadcast

I want to have a button on a (private) webpage on my site that, when clicked, starts an audio stream from the computer of the user who pressed the button.

Then, I want that stream to be accessible on another webpage on my site.

I'm aware of YouTube, Periscope, Spreaker, and others, but it is my understanding that the broadcast, using these services, is initiated through their website or apps. I'm ok with the broadcaster having to download a plugin on-the-fly (that is, after he has pressed the button), but I want to avoid the broadcaster having to install software, or having to use an alternative website.

So, what I'm looking for is a service/API that somehow takes a live audio recording within a browser, and repackages that as a live feed, to be used in an (embedded) player, elsewhere.

I'm aware of software like [Kurento](https://www.kurento.org), but I do not want to maintain the infrastructure myself. I just want the service/API to take care of that.

I'm also aware of join.me's API, but it's my understanding that the broadcaster still needs to install software to broadcast.

This service does not have to be free. And this service should (of course) not use Flash.

Does this exist?

Comment: Are you looking for something that capture your webcam or mic and broadcast it to web, so that client can see using browser only and nothing else? You may try with `vlc player`, you can use it as media server too. I have tried with web cam broadcasting only didn't try with audio

Comment: Thanks. What I want is to be able to press a button on a webpage which then results in recording my mic (or mic and video, but mic is enough), and broadcasting, streaming, it, presumably to an IP address and port, which can then be played, in a player like VLC, or inside a player on another webpage. VLC is an interesting thought, but this does not work from a webpage and requires the streaming computer to be accessible to the outside world.